# Webstorm doesn't allow to use "es2019" in tsconfig

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm trying to upgrade an Angular project into es2019. 
I've replaced the es2018 in the lib section in tsconfig into es2019 but the ide insists:

"Value should be one of: "es5, es6 ..." everything except t es2019.
What am I missing?

Edit: Webstorm 2019.1 was updated to 2019.3 and problem solved!

Comment: what is the  JavaScript version in WebStorm’s ? under  WebStorm’s Preferences (Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks. That was a hint. The webstorm was outdated.